# In Angular 6 app array.find function doesn't find existing element in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have a problem in my Angular 6 application and really can't find answer right now so please help me if you can. Thank you. The problem is next:

I have an array (userDocuments) with this content:

```
[{"DocumentId":1,"DocumentName":"Osobna iskaznica","Mark":"13994000"},{"DocumentId":2,"DocumentName":"Putovnica","Mark":"qprtobm777"}].
```

Dropdown is being populated from this array. Beside dropdown is button which is used for editing selected element content in dialog box.

```
<select id="select-document" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentId">
    <option *ngFor="let document of userDocuments" [value]="document.DocumentId">
    {{ document.DocumentName }} ({{ document.Mark }})</option>
    </select>
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-40 ml-1" type="button" (click)="openDocumentDailog(true)"> <i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
```

After component init when dropdown is being populated and hitting edit button dialog opens with data of selected array element. Everything works fine. Then I choose second value from dropdown and getting error about undefined element. Here is calling method for edit:

```
openDocumentDailog(edit: boolean) {
    const currentDoc = this.userDocuments.find(x => x.DocumentId === this.selectedDocumentId);
    console.log('array: ' + JSON.stringify(this.userDocuments));
    console.log('DocumentId: ' + this.selectedDocumentId);
    console.log(this.userDocuments.find(x => x.DocumentId === this.selectedDocumentId));

    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewDocumentComponent, {
      width: '400px',
      data: {
        userId: this.loggedUser.id,
        edit: edit,
        docId: edit ? currentDoc.DocumentId : null,
        docName: edit ? currentDoc.DocumentName : null,
        docMark: edit ? currentDoc.Mark : null
      }
    });

...
```

For variable currentDoc I'm getting error that is undefined in second search. As you can see I'm logging values. Here are results:

```
array: [{"DocumentId":1,"DocumentName":"Osobna iskaznica","Mark":"13994000"},{"DocumentId":2,"DocumentName":"Putovnica","Mark":"qprtobm777"}]
```

DocumentId: 1

```
Object { DocumentId: 1, DocumentName: "Osobna iskaznica", Mark: "13994000" }

array: [{"DocumentId":1,"DocumentName":"Osobna iskaznica","Mark":"13994000"},{"DocumentId":2,"DocumentName":"Putovnica","Mark":"qprtobm777"}]
```

DocumentId: 2

```
undefined
```

In code to me everything looks correct because documentId value (1 or 2) is present in one of array elements. Also I need to say when I choose back first value from dropdown also getting an error message of undefined element. After first edit next edits are not working anymore because of array.find method.

Am I missing something or is problem somewhere deeper? Thank you.

Zeljko

Comment: After two days of headache and immediately after posting the case I found that problem was with ...find(x => x.DocumentId === this.selectedDocumentId) but not sure why. In typescript selectedDocumentId is specified as a number (variable associated to dropdown ngModel) so everything looks correct in values comparing. Just in case I added plus(+) before this.selectedDocumentId for casting to number and look now app works. Don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: No I don't have.

Comment: I tried now with some selectedDocumentId initial value but without casting to number still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparison, we need to remember that `===` checks the value **and** the type. In your json, the id's are of type `number`, but whereas in your template you are using `value` that defaults to a string. If you want to keep your id as a `number`, you need to use `[ngValue]`:

```
<select id="select-document" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedDocumentId">
  <option *ngFor="let document of userDocuments" [ngValue]="document.DocumentId">
    // ...
  </option>
</select>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3ya4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: yes that's it. I changed to ngValue. Thank you 100x! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using strict comparison (e.g., ===), and it'is only true if the operands are of the same type and the contents match. The contents (DocumentId & this.selectedDocumentId) match, but operands are of different types. Try to use `==` instead of `===`, it seems that it doesn't find your document because of this:

```
const currentDoc = this.userDocuments.find(x => x.DocumentId == this.selectedDocumentId);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hello-angular-6-yghdtu)

Answer (score 0):

Is `selectedDocumentId` already initialized ?

you can do something like:

```
// the dropdown will select the first item by default
    constructor() {
      this.selectedDocumentId = this.userDocuments[1].DocumentId;
    }
```

Second:

`const currentDoc = this.userDocuments.find(x => x.DocumentId === this.selectedDocumentId);`

`x.DocumentId` is a `int` but `this.selectedDocumentId` is a string, you compare an `int` with a `string` with `===`.

solution:
You can either do `{"DocumentId":"1"(string),"DocumentName":"Osobna iskaznica","Mark":"13994000"}`, ...

or do `x.DocumentId === parseInt(this.selectedDocumentId,10)` to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it is when array is filled with data. As stated below in answer I changed code from value to ngValue to keep variable as a number and now is all ok. Thank you.